# How does firefox chose which plugin to use?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, plugins, quicktime

I have written a plugin which allows the user to view multi-page TIFF
images within firefox. The problem is that Quicktime also thinks it
can view TIFF images. How does Firefox chose which one gets used?

through trial and error I've determined that:

- Sometimes, my plugin (Accel VIewTIFF)
  just runs, and everyone is happy.
- Sometimes I need to disable Quicktime
  in the Add-ons window.
- Sometimes I need to remove the 
  QuickTime plugin files from the / 
  Library/Internet Plug-ins folder (I'm 
  on a mac)
- Sometimes I can put QuickTime BACK
  after having successfully run Accel
  ViewTIFF.

I've yet to figure out when (if ever) each step is necessary.

Please help me escape the cargo cult! (or at least point me to the
right place in a manual.)

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official word from Firefox is that among the valid plugins for that time, the choice is "Consistent but random" meaning that once it makes a choice, if nothing changes, it will always make that choice, but they won't tell you how they make the initial choice.

Lovely.

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences window, under the applications tab, select the file type you need, and select it to always use your plugin. The "Always ask" option somehow doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok, but what if there is no line for image/TIFF? There doesn't seem to be a "add Mime type" button there...